# At what point in a Web API app can I intercept the URI arguments and route the calls accordingly?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, database-schema, lifecycle, asp.net-web-api-routing

Note: This question is indeed somewhat similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21388655/can-i-programmatically-determine-the-database-context-to-use-based-on-user-cre), but I think I can put it in a simpler and more specific way.

I'm using Castle Windsor to intercept the URI passed to my Web API app to register the appropriate concrete class to the Controller's constructor.

What I want to be able to do is pass a "site number" on the URI, perhaps always as either the first or last arg. IOW, for site 42, instead of

```
http://localhost:28642/api/platypi/GetAll
```

...it would be:

```
http://localhost:28642/api/platypi/42/GetAll
```

-or:

```
http://localhost:28642/api/platypi/GetAll/42
```

When my Web API app first "sees"/intercepts the URI, I want to note that site number so that I can assign the desired concrete Repository to be registered by Castle Windsor. I want to be able to do this:

```
public class RepositoriesInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        if (siteNum == 42)
        {
            container.Register(
            Component.For<IDepartmentRepository>().ImplementedBy<DepartmentRepository42>().LifestylePerWebRequest(),
                Component.For<IInventoryItemRepository>().ImplementedBy<InventoryItemRepository42>().LifestylePerWebRequest(),
            . . .
        }
        else if (siteNum = 77)
        {
            container.Register(
        Component.For<IDepartmentRepository>().ImplementedBy<DepartmentRepository77>().LifestylePerWebRequest(),
                Component.For<IInventoryItemRepository>().ImplementedBy<InventoryItemRepository77>().LifestylePerWebRequest(),
            . . .
        }
```

In this way I can give site 42 its data, site 77 its data (each site uses a different database that share a common schema).

So: At which point in my Web API app's lifecycle can I hijack the URI, so as to assign the appropriate val to the global siteNum variable, so that it has been assigned before the IWindsorInstaller method runs?

### UPDATE

Thanks to Mr. Slate, but if I were to do that, would this Controller code:

```
public DepartmentsController(IDepartmentRepository deptsRepository)
{
    if (deptsRepository == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("deptsRepository");
    }
    _deptsRepository = deptsRepository;
}
```

...become:

```
public DepartmentsController(IDepartmentRepository deptsRepository)
{
    if (deptsRepository == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("deptsRepository");
    }
    _deptsRepository = deptsRepository(siteNum);
}
```

...or???

And I'm still left with the problem of where do I intercept the incoming URI before Castle Windsor / the Controller gets it, so that I can set the appropriate value to the global /  siteNum var?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of extensions points that you can use to achieve this, personally I use this one for a similar result.

Create a custom model binder by extending `IModelBinder` something like this:

```
public class SiteManagerModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        #region IModelBinder Members

        public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            if (bindingContext.Model != null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot update instances");
            }

            // Apply your condition to determine if site number is in Url.
            if (controllerContext.RouteData.Values['siteNum']!=null)
            {
               // probably want to resolve this from container just hard coding as example, assumption is that SiteManager, does the repository bits for you.
               return new SiteManager((int)controllerContext.RouteData.Values['siteNum']);
            }

            return null;
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Okay so now we jus tneed to register our new ModelBinder:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    { 
        ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(SiteManager), new SiteManagerModelBinder ());
```

Okay and now in our controller all we do is add the SiteManager as a parameter of any Action and it will get filled in by our ModelBinder.

```
public class DepartmentsController: Controller {

    public ActionResult AnyAction(SiteManager siteManager, int whateverElse, ViewModel model)
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: Looks very promising, but is this a basic/generic MVC-only solution, or does it apply also to Web API, for which my Controller implements ApiController instead of Controller:
public class DepartmentsController : ApiController

Comment: Is the URI being passed / which is invoking the Web API app accessible from within Global.asax's Application_Start() handler?

Comment: No, the URI is not accessible in the application_start, this is just the place where you will register application wide thigs. I am not too sure about the web API but as I understand it, it is largley the same and goes through the same pipeline. Give it a try and let me know, there are other ways I can think of to achive a solution.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: Assuming I can access siteNum from siteManager, I will see if this (siteManager) is available in RepositoriesInstaller. Controller is too late, because once a particular/the specific Controller has been instantiated by the routing engine, that is the level at which/the place where the site number will have to already be known.

Comment: Well there is a few ways you can do this, you could replace SiteManager with SiteRepository directly if you prefer, but it's always good to have an extra business layer between.

Comment: Where does the SiteManagerModelBinder class need to be, or does it not matter (anywhere in the project)?

Comment: It doesn't matter, you just need to register it. It could even be in a different assembly.

Answer (score 1):

I'd change the constructor on DepartmentRepository() to pass the site num and use that to get the connectionstring. Then in your webconfig create a connectionstring for each site.

Comment: Updated my question with a response to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different way you could try rather using Castle Windsor which might be better:

Create a repository factory like this:

```
public interface IRepositoryFactory
{
    Repository CreateRepositoryById(int id);
}
```

Create a component selector to select the correct repository based on the name like this:

```
public class RepositoryFactorySelector : DefaultTypedFactoryComponentSelector
{
    protected override string GetComponentName(MethodInfo method, object[] arguments)
    {
        return (method.Name.EndsWith("ById") && arguments.Length >= 1 && arguments[0] is int)
                   ? string.Format("Repository{0}", arguments[0]) 
                   : base.GetComponentName(method, arguments);
    }
}
```

Register your repositories like this:

```
public class RepositoryInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    #region IWindsorInstaller Members

    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<Repository>().Configure(c=>c.Named(c.Implementation.Name)));

        container.Register(
            Component.For<RepositoryFactorySelector, ITypedFactoryComponentSelector>().LifestyleSingleton(),
            Component.For<IRepositoryFactory>().AsFactory(c => c.SelectedWith<RepositoryFactorySelector>()));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

As long as Windsor is loading your controllers using a constroller factory you can now do this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IRepositoryFactory RepositoryFactory { get; set; }

    public ActionResult Index(int siteNum)
    {
        var repository = RepositoryFactory.CreateRepositoryById(siteNum);

        // tada!

        return View();
    }

}
```

For reference my global.asax.cs:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        Container = new WindsorContainer();
        Container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>(); 

        Container.Install(FromAssembly.This()); 

        var controllerFactory = new WindsorControllerFactory(Container.Kernel);
        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(controllerFactory);
    }

    public WindsorContainer Container;
}
```

And my repositories:

```
public abstract class Repository
{
}

public class Repository1 : Repository
{ 
}

public class Repository2 : Repository
{ 
}
```

Comment: This all seems very clever, but I don't have a "View"; this is Web API, not MVC.