# ASP.Net MVC using IoC Windsor Castle - components are waiting for dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

### Description of my Windsor resolving problem

I got MVC web.api project.

I use Windsor Castle for IoC. But at this moment I have a problem with resolving already registred components.

Specifically, I get this error during I am checking for potentially misconfigured components:

> Some dependencies of this component could not be statically resolved.
>   'FoodRate.Web.DataServices.PlaceDataService' is waiting for the following dependencies:
>   - Service 'FoodRate.Web.DataServices.PlaceMapper' which was registered but is also waiting for dependencies.
>   'FoodRate.Web.DataServices.PlaceMapper' is waiting for the following dependencies:
>   - Service 'FoodRate.Web.DataServices.PlaceTypeMapper' which was registered but is also waiting for dependencies.
>
> Some dependencies of this component could not be statically resolved.
>   'FoodRate.Web.DataServices.PlaceMapper' is waiting for the following dependencies:
>   - Service 'FoodRate.Web.DataServices.PlaceTypeMapper' which was registered but is also waiting for dependencies.

I understand why DataService named PlaceDataService has to wait for its dependencies. But I do not understand why there is a problem with PlaceMapper and its dependency PlaceTypeMapper.

I checked the status of the PlaceTypeMapper resolving inside the container) and PlaceTypeMapper can be resloved without errors.

[image]

And as shown on the scren above the PlaceTypeMapper does not have any dependency. And status is really:

> All requierd dependencies can be resolved.

### Class definitions

I have attached my classes definitions:

```
public interface IMapper
{
}
```

PlaceMapper class definition:

```
public interface IPlaceMapper : IMapper
{
    /* ... some public definitions  */
}

public class PlaceMapper : IPlaceMapper
{
    private readonly IPlaceTypeMapper placeTypeMapper;
    private readonly IGeoLocationMapper geoLocationMapper;

    public PlaceMapper(IGeoLocationMapper geoLocationMapper, IPlaceTypeMapper placeTypeMapper)
    {
        this.geoLocationMapper = geoLocationMapper;
        this.placeTypeMapper = placeTypeMapper;
    }
    /* .... Some public methods  */
}
```

PlaceTypeMapper definition:

```
public interface IPlaceTypeMapper : IMapper
{
    /* ... Some public definitions  */
}

public class PlaceTypeMapper : IPlaceTypeMapper
{
    public PlaceTypeDto ConvertPlaceTypeToPlaceTypeDto(PlaceType placeType)
    {
                /* .... */
    }

    public IList<PlaceTypeDto> ConvertPlaceTypeToPlaceTypeDto(IList<PlaceType> placeTypes)
    {
                /* .... */
    }
}
```

DataService definition:

```
public interface IDataService
{
}

public class PlaceDataService : IPlaceDataService
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;
    private readonly IPlaceMapper placeMapper;
    private readonly IGeoLocationMapper geoLocationMapper;

    public PlaceDataService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IPlaceMapper placeMapper, IGeoLocationMapper geoLocationMapper)
    {
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        this.placeMapper = placeMapper;
        this.geoLocationMapper = geoLocationMapper;
    }

    public PlaceDto GetPlace(int id)
    {
                /* ... */
    }

    public IList<PlaceDto> GetPlaceByLocation(GeoLocationDto geoLocation)
    {
               /* ... */
    }
}
```

And Windsor installer section (inter alia):

```
container.Register(Component.For<IUnitOfWork>().
    ImplementedBy<UnitOfWork>().
    LifestyleTransient()); 

container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly().
    BasedOn<IMapper>().
    WithService.AllInterfaces().
    LifestyleSingleton());

container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly().
    BasedOn<IDataService>().
    WithService.AllInterfaces().
    LifestyleTransient());
```

I will be grateful for any recommendations..

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21341636/how-can-i-tell-the-web-api-castle-windsor-routing-engine-to-use-a-different-da/21355365#21355365

Comment: thanks for your comment. But i do not see anythink what could solve my problem...